# How to change styles except ::before?

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to change style of my `a` element by `::hover` but I dont want to change a `::before` element of it. How to avoid effect on `::before`? There is my code I've got.

```css
header nav a {
  width: 14%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
header nav a:before {
  content: "\002D";
  padding: 0px 40px;
}
header nav a:hover {
  color: lime;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="">Home</a>
    <a href="">About</a>
    <a href="">Blog</a>
    <a href="">Contact</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Simply set `color` of `header nav a:before{..`

Comment: thank you, I didn't excpect that easy solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add color to :before content...

```css
header nav a{
  width: 14%;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}
header nav a:before{
  content: "\002D";
  padding: 0px 40px;
  color: #000
} 
header nav a:before:hover{
  color: #000
}
header nav a:hover{
        color: lime;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="">Home</a>
    <a href="">About</a>
    <a href="">Blog</a>
    <a href="">Contact</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```